# Why is DateTime lastdate giving a different date than the one I am trying to convert?

Tags: asp.net, date, datetime-format

I am attempting to convert the date fetched from a datepicker to a different format . The date format on my system is : "25/04/2018" which I want to convert to "2018-04-25".
I tried :

```
 string tbdate = textboxdate.Text;
            DateTime lastdate = DateTime.ParseExact(tbdate,
                       "dd/mm/yyyy",
                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            string newFormat = lastdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But the value I get in lastdate is "25/01/2018 12:04:00 AM". Why is showing a different date.I need it to be the current date.

Comment: `dd/mm/yyyy` need to be `dd/MM/yyyy`. `mm` refers to minutes and `MM` to months

Comment: oh..yes i missed that..thanks.